# Where is the right place to put PagerAdapter, RecyclerViewAdapter in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, android-mvvm

When I implement my app using MVVM architecture. I always have a question of where should I put implementations of `PagerAdapter` and `RecyclerViewAdapter`. Now I put into `Fragments` as inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I think It does not matter because they are a helper class, but I think you should not put them in activity/frament as an inner class, because they can make this class bigger, just put them into the same package with activity/frament.

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on **MVVM** architecture.
The best practice is you should not put `Adapter` class as an inner class. Just put them in the same package.